# ACF: post query, hide duplicate values

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, wp-query, query-posts, advanced-custom-fields

I'm querying an ACF field, and displaying all the results on the front-end like so—
PHP:

```
            <ul class="category-menu-items">
                <?php 

                // args
                $args = array(
                    'numberposts' => -1,
                    'post_type' => 'wpsc-product'
                );

                // get results
                $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

                // The Loop
                ?>
                <?php if( $the_query->have_posts() ): ?>
                    <ul class="inside-category-menu-items">
                    <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
                        <li class="category-menu-item">
                            <a href="/shop/?view_type=default&product_search=<?php $remove = array(" ", ",", "/", ".", ":", "-", "–", "—", "!", "?", ";");
echo strtolower(str_replace($remove, "+", get_field('products_page_designer_name'))); ?>">
                                <?php the_field('products_page_designer_name'); ?>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                    </ul>
                <?php endif; ?>

                <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
            </ul>
```

This works great, the only problem is the values of some of the fields are duplicates of others, e.g. It will output a list like so:

```
Value 01
Value 02
Value 02
Value 03
Value 03
```

etc etc. but I only want to display one instance of each, thus if there's a duplicate value it will be hidden. Is this at all possible? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could pass all the fields into an array during your while loop, strip the array of duplicates, and then run a foreach loop on that array.  It would look something like this:

```
<?php 
$designers = array();
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
     $designers[] = get_field('products_page_designer_name');
endwhile;

// This will strip out any values that are identical.
$designers = array_unique( $designers );

// Run through your unique array of designers
foreach ( $designers as $designer ) { ?>
    <li class="category-menu-item">
        <a href="/shop/?view_type=default&product_search=<?php
            $remove = array(" ", ",","/", ".", ":", "-", "–", "—", "!", "?", ";");
            echo strtolower(str_replace($remove, "+", $designer)); ?>">
            <?php echo $designer; ?>
        </a>
    </li>
<?php } ?>
```

Note that I haven't tested the syntax or the code.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `get_field_object` function to get all field that been create for a post and generate by ACF.

Here is code to get all custom fields from group id:

```
<?php
$groupID='23';
$custom_field_keys = get_post_custom_keys($groupID);
foreach ( $custom_field_keys as $key => $fieldkey )
{
    if (stristr($fieldkey,'field_'))
        {
            // get_field_object( $field_name, $post_id, $options )
        // - $value has already been loaded for us, no point to load it again in the get_field_object function
        $field = get_field_object($fieldkey, $groupID);

        echo '';
            echo '<span><span>' . $field['label'] . '</span>:';
            echo ''. get_field($field['name']) . '</span>';
        echo '';
     }

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

### EDIT: They will always return the same value if they have the same field name

`get_field('field_name1')` and `the_field('field_name1')` are the same value if you use the same field_name!

Take a look at the docs for [get_field](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/functions/get_field/) and [the_field](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/functions/the_field/).

For `the_field()` it says:

> this is the same as “echo get_field($field_name)”

---

One way to do so would be to put then in an array and then check to see if they are in the array using `in_array()`.

I would instead use a class or function to build an object or an array with the correct values and then supply it to the template with the preformed values.  **Keep the logic out of your template/view!**

### MVC Principles

Here is a [presentation about MVC in Wordpress](http://iandunn.name/content/presentations/wp-oop-mvc/mvc.php#/) by Ian Dunn.

**Essentially what you should want to do is eliminate code reuse as much as possible**.  That is what MVC tries to accomplish **as well as keeping everything in a logical structure**.

Basically what he outlines is this:

#### MVC: Controllers

- Direct traffic within the application
- Collect data from models, pass to views
- Doesn't maniuplate the data

#### MVC: Models

- Data layer
- Handles business/domain logic
- Does the heavy lifting

#### MVC: Views

- Only the presentation of the data - HTML/CSS
- Use inline PHP, but sparingly
- **No data manipulation**

Fat Models, Skinny Controllers

**For example:**

```
function get_menu_items_object() {
    $menu_items = array();
    $add_to_menu_items = array(
    'designer_name1' => get_field('products_page_designer_name'),
    'designer_name2' => the_field('products_page_designer_name')
    );
   foreach($add_to_menu_items as $item_key => $item) {
        if (!in_array($item, $menu_items)){
        $menu_items[$item_key] = $item;
    } else {
        $menu_items[$item_key] = '';
    }
    return (object) $menu_items;
}
```

Then all you would have to do is:

```
$menu_items_object = get_menu_items_object();
echo $menu_items_object->designer_name1; //value echoed
echo $menu_items_object->designer_name2; //value echoed.  If '' then it is nothing
```